# Storing HTML5 video in cache as preloader

Tags: html, caching, video, buffer, preload

I need a video to preload completely before playback, if i let the video play from start until finish in the background on one page then on the next page play that same video again, would the video be played from cache and hence no buffering would happen? Also, if they only viewed 50% of the video on the first page, does this cache 50% of the video so that on the second page the buffer will start from 50%?

Thank you!

Comment: if the video is small(1mb) and you use modern browsers you can use localStorage, websql, sesssionStorage... you need to get the video with ajax as datauri.

Comment: The video is actually going to be about 250MB.